# Getting the first occurence of an element, independent of parents

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to write a CSS selector which matches the first occurrence of an element with class "icon". The elements haven't got a common parent (as seen below), so the `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` pseudos didn't work for me.

The HTML markup isn't very good, but its specification, so it's not possible to change it.

Is there any CSS only solution, to match the first occurence of an element?

```html
<div>
    <div class="icon"></div> <!-- only this should be matched -->
    <p class="categoryTitle">Category 1</p>
    <ul>..</ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <p class="categoryTitle">Category 1</p>
    <ul>..</ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <p class="categoryTitle">Category 1</p>
    <ul>..</ul>
</div>
```

OR

```html
<div>
  <!-- nothing here --> 
</div>
<div>
    <div class="icon"></div>  <!-- only this should be matched -->
    <p class="categoryTitle">Category 1</p>
    <ul>..</ul>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <p class="categoryTitle">Category 1</p>
    <ul>..</ul>
</div>
```

OR

```html
<div>
  <!-- nothing here --> 
</div>
<div>
  <!-- nothing here too -->
</div>
<div>
    <div class="icon"></div>  <!-- only this should be matched -->
    <p class="categoryTitle">Category 1</p>
    <ul>..</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you could add some js code, then you could use that to change the element's style. Otherwise, without changing the html itself in some way (like adding an id to the first icon, or some other way), I don't see a way to do this.

Comment: Might also be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You'd have to find out which of the parent `div` elements have `.icon` children in the first place, which you can't do with CSS selectors. The jQuery selector `.icon:first` does exactly what you want, but `:first` is not part of CSS.

Comment: Well, the problem lies more in navigating the `.icon` elements' hierarchies than finding out which `div`s have `.icons`, but you get the idea...

Comment: It's just not possible with that setup, i accept that. We now have a class "loaded" on a container div, when it gets content. Now a selector like this is possible: "div.loaded:nth-of-type(2) .icon"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you'll have to use some sort of javascript to do this. I've actually just done this on a project of my own.

jQuery:

```
$('.Icon:first').addClass('myclass'); // or .css('attribute', 'value') depending on what you want.
```

The above script will at all times ONLY affect the first match of `.Icon` it finds.

I know it's not CSS, but you can't really do what you want to achieve by only using CSS.